# Calculus identity for expression related to remainder in Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have come across the following (claimed) identity in some lecture notes that I'm reading, but I haven't managed to rederive it so far!
It is claimed that for any positive integer vector $\gamma$, $|\gamma|=1$, we have
$$ \partial^\gamma\sum_{|\alpha|=k}\frac{|\alpha|}{\alpha!}\int_0^1 s^{|\alpha|-1}x^\alpha \partial^\alpha \psi(sx) \, \mathrm ds = \sum_{|\beta|=k-1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{\beta!}x^{\beta}\partial^{\beta+\gamma}\psi(x), \qquad \forall\; \psi\in C^k$$
Does anyone see how to obtain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here we go. We have $\sum_{|\alpha|=k} \frac{|\alpha|}{\alpha!} \partial^\alpha \psi(sx) x^\alpha = \frac{1}{(k-1)!} \frac{d^k}{ds^k} \psi(sx).$ Thus
\begin{align}
\partial^\gamma \sum_{|\alpha|=k} \frac{|\alpha|}{\alpha!} \int_0^1 s^{|\alpha|-1}\partial^\alpha \psi(sx) x^\alpha \, \mathrm ds 
&= \partial^\gamma \int_0^1 s^{k-1} \frac{1}{(k-1)!} \frac{d^k}{ds^k} \psi(sx) \, \mathrm ds \\
&= \partial^\gamma \left[\sum_{\ell=1}^{k} (-1)^{\ell+1}s^{k-\ell}\frac{1}{(k-\ell)!} \frac{d^{k-\ell}}{ds^{k-\ell}}\psi(sx) \right]_{s=0}^1 \\
&= \partial^\gamma \sum_{\ell=1}^{k-1} (-1)^{\ell+1} \frac{1}{(k-\ell)!} \frac{d^{k-\ell}}{ds^{k-\ell}}\Bigg|_{s=1} \psi(sx) \\
&\quad + (-1)^{k+1} \partial^\gamma (\psi(x)-\psi(0)) \\
&= \partial^\gamma \sum_{\ell=1}^{k} (-1)^{\ell+1} \sum_{|\beta|=k-\ell} \frac{1}{\beta!} \partial^{\beta}\psi(x)x^\beta \\
&= \partial^\gamma \sum_{\ell=0}^{k-1} (-1)^{k+\ell+1}\sum_{|\beta|=\ell}\frac{1}{\beta!} \partial^\beta \psi(x) x^\beta \\
&= (-1)^{k+1}\sum_{|\beta|<k} \frac{(-1)^{|\beta|}}{\beta!}\partial^{\beta+\gamma} \psi(x) x^\beta.
\end{align}
This is similar to what was claimed (the claim seems to be wrong).